# Java singleton on enum and ConcurrentHashMap. Thread-safety issues?

Tags: java, concurrency, enums, singleton

I want to keep temporarily blocked users in a HashMap located in a singleton:

```
public enum BlockedUsersRepository {

    REPOSITORY;

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, User> blockedUsers = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, User>();

    /* Static 'instance' method */
    public static BlockedUsersRepository getInstance( ) {
            return REPOSITORY;
    }}
```

A user is getting into the map after a number of unsuccessful attempts to enter card number. I do it by launching the following methods from User class:

```
    public void addBlockedUser(User user) {
            blockedUsers.put(user.getEmail(),user);
    }

    public void removeBlockedUser(User user) {
            blockedUsers.remove(user.getEmail());
    }
```

The question is: do I undertake ENOUGH measures for thread-safety? How can I model concurrent access to the map in Terminal to make sure it really works or fails? Is it an appropriate approach at all, because I am afraid it's lame because the singletone plays a role of kinda a global variable accessible/modifiable by a number of User instances. I am new to the concurrency in Java and ask you to be lenient. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The enum as singleton is a threadsafe way of creating one. You have `final` on the ConcurrentMap meaning no issues at that point.

ConcurrentHashMap can not be broken by concurrent writes.

A concurrent addBlockedUser/removeBlockedUser may lead to the user being blocked or unblocked. But imo both results are ok as you dont have a constraint saying a user has to be blocked for at least x seconds to be unblockable.

Problems that might be present but not directly threading issues.

- Did you make sure that the email is unique? If not, only one of theses users can be blocked at the same time.
- Did you make sure that email is not null? ConcurrentHashMap can not handle the case, and would violate uniqueness.
- How do you handle the case somebody changes his email?

Comment: I was mostly concerned about thread-safety, the rest is not as critical since it is just an educational project. Thanks a lot for supporting.